# Operads and their applications to define homomorphisms

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, operads

I have already commenced studying the notion of operads via following Kapranov & Ginzburg's paper ([Koszul Duality for Operads](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1228)) and for instance: [Varieties of dialgebras and conformal algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611501) the P.S. Kolesnikov's paper. I want to use this notion for the following problem, but I am not sure about how to use that:

> Problem: Assume $D$ be a dialgebra. Let's consider its derivation and  denote it by $Der(D)$, which has a Lie algebras structure. I want to define a dialgebra homomorphism between $D$ and $Der(D)$. How can I define such a homomorphism?

Comment: How is $Der(D)$ a dialgebra?

Comment: $Der(D)$ is not a dialgebra. Is it possible to define a homomorphism between algebras from different varieties?